# How to fix Python 3 code to extract specific lines from a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, parsing, extract

I'm trying to extract specific lines from a 4.7 GB text file into another text file.

I'm pretty new to python 3.7.1 and this was the best code I could come up with.

Here is a sample of what the text file looks like:

```
C00629618|N|TER|P|201701230300133512|15C|IND|DOE, JOHN A|PLEASANTVILLE|WA|00000|PRINCIPAL|DOUBLE NICKEL ADVISORS|01032017|40|H6CA34245|SA01251735122|1141239|||2012520171368850783
C00501197|N|M2|P|201702039042410893|15|IND|DOE, JANE|THE LODGE|GA|00000|UNUM|SVP, CORPORATE COMMUNICATIONS|01312017|230||PR1890575345050|1147350||P/R DEDUCTION ($115.00 BI-WEEKLY)|4020820171370029335
C00177436|N|M2|P|201702039042410893|15|IND|DOE, JOHN|RED ROOM|ME|00000|UNUM|SVP, DEPUTY GENERAL COUNSEL, BUSINESS|01312017|384||PR2260663445050|1147350||P/R DEDUCTION ($192.00 BI-WEEKLY)|4020820171370029336
C00177436|N|M2|P|201702039042410895|15|IND|PALMER, LAURA|TWIN PEAKS|WA|00000|UNUM|EVP, GLOBAL SERVICES|01312017|384||PR2283905245050|1147350||P/R DEDUCTION ($192.00 BI-WEEKLY)|4020820171370029342
C00501197|N|M2|P|201702039042410894|15|IND|COOPER, DALE|TWIN PEAKS|WA|00000|UNUM|SVP, CORP MKTG & PUBLIC RELAT.|01312017|384||PR2283904845050|1147350||P/R DEDUCTION ($192.00 BI-WEEKLY)|4020820171370029339
```

And this is the code I've written:

```py
import re

with open("data.txt", 'r') as rf:
    for line in rf:
        field_match = re.match('^(.*):(.*)$',line)

        if field_match :
            (key) = field_match.groups()
            if key == "C00501197" :
                print(rec.split('|'))

with open('extracted_data.txt','w') as wf:
    wf.write(line)
```

I need to extract full lines that contain the id C00501197 and then have the program write those extracted lines into another txt file, but as of now it's only extracting one line and that line doesn't begin with the id I want extracted.

Comment: I'd strongly recommend using the `csv` module, e.g. `csv.reader` with a custom `delimiter` argument, for stuff like this. Don't roll your own parser with regular expressions, let the libraries do the work for you.

Comment: Also, for these type of manipulation, you could try to look into shell commands ? I find it quite useful if it's a one time thing : e.g. for bash ```cat data.txt |  grep  C00501197 > extracted_data.txt ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use regex if you can avoid it. `csv` is a good choice, or use simple string manipulation.

```
ans = []

with open('data.txt') as rf:
    for line in rf:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.startswith("C00501197"):
            ans.append(line)

with open('extracted_data.txt', 'w') as wf:
    for line in ans:
        wf.write(line)
```

Your output code was a bit busted as well - always wrote out the last line in the file, not the selected records.

Answer (score 1):

You should implement the built in `csv` module that comes standard with python. It can easily parse each line into a list. Try something like this:

```
import csv

with open('text.txt', 'r') as file:
    my_reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter='|')
    for row in my_reader:
        if row[0] == 'C00501197':
            print(row)
```

This should output the lines you want. You can then do whatever you want to process them, and save them again.

Comment: That's not a very helpful text sample, as it does not contain any colons, and your regular expression explicitly looks for colons.

Comment: @JohnGordon I'm very confused. I do not even gave a regex in my code...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass through regex, just split the line based on separator and check the nth field you're interested in:

```
found_lines = []

with open("data.txt", 'r') as rf:
    for line_file in rf:
        line = line_file.split("|")
        if line[0] == "C00501197" :
            found_lines.append( line )

with open('extracted_data.txt','w') as wf:
    for found_line in found_lines :
        wf.write("|".join(map(str,found_line)))
```

This should work.

Comment: Yes, that should work, but I don't think you should include a `break`. OP has indicated that "I need to extract full lines" (plural lines).